# c# set performanceCounters enabled=true in code

Tags: c#, app-config, performancecounter

I'm using this method to count my app sent bytes:

```
string currId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();

            PerformanceCounter dataSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            dataSentCounter.CategoryName=".NET CLR Networking";
            dataSentCounter.CounterName="Bytes Sent";
            dataSentCounter.InstanceName =  "curr"+"["+currId+"]";
            dataSentCounter.ReadOnly = true;

            float sumSent = 0;
            sumSent = dataSentCounter.NextValue();

            uploadSize_Label.Content = sumSent.ToString();
```

It works fine with app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <performanceCounters enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to set `performanceCounters enabled="true"` without using app.config (without any configuraton file - only by aplication code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [PerformanceCountersElement.Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.performancecounterselement.enabled.aspx) property.

```
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        NetSectionGroup netGroup = (NetSectionGroup)config.SectionGroups.Get("system.net");
        netGroup.Settings.PerformanceCounters.Enabled = true;

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: All I could do with PerformanceCountersElement.Enabled is: System.Net.Configuration.PerformanceCountersElement perf = new System.Net.Configuration.PerformanceCountersElement();
   perf.Enabled = "true";
but don`t know how to use it at all.

Comment: Thank You ... it still needs app.config (app.exe.config), but it is good enought to set that parameter and create a file if parameter/file not exist.

Comment: @m.h Welcome...however I would really advise to keep these types of items within the app.config so you can turn them on/off as needed without a recompile whenever you desire.